# Relations and partial with some set A and a relation R b|d

Tags: relations, order-theory

$A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and on B=$A\times A$ we define a relation R as follows :

$<a,b>R<c,d>$ if and only if $a \leq c $ And $b|d$ (without Remainder)
a) Prove that R is partial Order on B=$A\times A$ 
b) find the smallest element in B related to partial order R

**me and some friends couldn't find anti-reflexive property  on the relation R it seems there must be some mistake or something we not seeing**

**in my course they define it with anti-relexive**

Comment: Edited , You are right

Comment: And why would you want it to be anti-reflexive, when a a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) must be **reflexive**? By the way, you have two partial orderings of $A$: one is $\leq$, the order inherited from the natural numbers, and $|$, defined as $a|b$ if $ak=b$ for some $k$. Then, $B$ is the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order) of these partial order relations; thus, a partial ordering itself.

Comment: Im sorry, in my course they define it with anti-relexive

Comment: Ok, so maybe that course defines partial orders to be [strict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders). You can prove that the order in $B$ is strict (an irreflexive and transitive order) if you define $(a,b)R(c,d)$ iff $a\leq c$ and $b|d$, with the restriction that at least one of $a \neq c$ or $b\neq d$ occurs.

Comment: but  how can i find $<a,b>,<a,b>$ , as you say , $a \neq c$ or  $b \neq d$

Comment: Given that $a=a$ and $b=b$, if we define $R$ as I suggested in my previous comment, then $(a,b)R(a,b)$ is false, for all $(a,b)\in B$; thus $R$ is irreflexive. But I would actually suggest that you check what you really need to prove. It seems more natural to me that for this exercise, you should use the non-strict definition of partial order. After all, the order relations from which $R$ is built, $\leq$ and $|$, are not strict...

Comment: Yes it seems to me also .. , i think they ment to be the non-strict definition that mybe it was the previous official definition in the course.